# В чём смысл знаков "Скрытый талант" и "Непризнаный гений"?

Tags: обсуждение, знаки, золотые-знаки

Пытаюсь понять, а в чём собственно смысл этих двух знаков ([Скрытый талант](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/50/tenacious) и [Непризнанный гений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero)).
Ведь если ответ принят, то скорее всего он хороший (правильный), а значит и рейтинг у него будет высокий. А тут получается награду за нулевой рейтинг дают...
Объясните, пожалуйста, смысл.

Comment: Тут надо вспомнить важное различие между принятием ответа и рейтингом: в общем случае, автор принимает тот ответ который был максимально полезен лично ему - тогда как оценки (плюсы и минусы) формирующие рейтинг, являются выражением мнения сообщества... а оно далеко не всегда совпадает с мнением автора вопроса. Из-за различий в мнениях автора и сообщества, принятые ответы не всегда имеют высокий (или ненулевой) рейтинг. Ну а смысл этих знаков наверное в том, чтобы поддержать тех отвечающих, которые (пока что) не получают поддержки со стороны сообщества (это чисто предположение, точно я не знаю)

Comment: @yar85, А разве автор вопроса не может поставить плюс за ответ? То есть помимо того, что выбрал ответ, ещё и плюсанул его. Так наверно большинство и делает. И тогда получить ситуацию с выбранным ответом и 0 рейтингом у него почти не реально...

Comment: Да, автор может плюсануть. Но вот по факту, это не всегда делается: сейчас [поиск показывает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0) что таких ответов (принятых, и с нулевым рейтингом) 36590 из 418420 (≈8,7%). Действительно, редкая ситуация, но она случается :)

Comment: @yar85, ясно, спасибо) теперь смысл понятен)
если оформите это в качестве ответа, я отмечу его принятым)

Comment: Предлагаю еще немного подождать ответов, от тех кто с большей уверенностью сможет объяснить смысл знаков (мне не хочется ответ давать на чистом предположении, ведь сам не совсем понимаю с какой целью эти знаки выдаются - и тоже интересно узнать об этом). **upd.:** Ну вот, я подозревал что ошибаюсь в чем-то, и не зря)))

Comment: Подумаешь, нулевой... у меня на SO.EN есть пара принятых автором ответов с отрицательным рейтингом.

Comment: @Akina суть знака в том, что твои ответы не замечают, а отрицательная оценка говорит, что ответ твой заметили. конечно, эта система подсчёта не идеальна т.к. +1/-1 будет 0, хотя кол-во оценок равно 2. хотя вероятность такого исхода ниже, всё равно, это весомая доля

Comment: @return Я имел в виду, что суть/качество/полезность/прочее ответа абстрактно и для конкретного автора вопроса могут различаться как небо и земля. Собственно, это следствие того, что SO позиционирует себя как QA, и на самом деле на то, помог автору ответ или нет - глубоко плевать, ибо этот момент даже не рассматривается в идеологии сайта.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Отвечаю как человек, обладающий знаком [непризнанный гений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51) :)

> Разве автор вопроса не может поставить плюс за ответ?

**Не может**. Если он только что зарегистрировался на сайте, и задал свой первый вопрос, то его репутация равняется 1, а привилегия [`Голосовать за`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) присуждается только за 15 баллов репутации.

За один плюс в данный момент дают 10 баллов, за принятие ответа — 2. То есть автор вопроса, даже после принятия ответа и получения голоса за вопрос, самостоятельно голосовать не может (и имеет 13 репутации).

Думаю, что смысл знака в том, чтобы мотивировать специалистов отвечать на вопросы новичков в узких направлениях.

Comment: Ах вот оно что)) 
Просто не поверите, но я пока ещё ни одного вопроса не задал на стековерфлоу, только отвечаю и помогаю другим :) поэтому и не знал механику голосования, можно ли выбрать ответ и сразу проголосовать... и вот это вот всё.
Спасибо, что объяснили на понятном примере) Пойду дальше ответы писать :)

Comment: Этот ответ просто обязан получать плюсики признания: гениальности, и редкости знака :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 кстати, а почему у вас в профиле не видно этого знака? 

Или он потом пропадает? Или я не туда смотрю?

Comment: @SergeyZh Смотрите [основной профиль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/339283/nomnoms12?tab=badges)

Comment: @nomnoms12 ой, простите) теперь увидел)  совсем забыл, что сервисы объединены и между ними нужно переключаться. Первый раз просто на meta, обычно на стеке сижу))

Comment: *Если он только что зарегистрировался на сайте, и задал свой первый вопрос, то его репутация равняется 1* Ну получить первые 100 баллов совсем несложно, всего-то и надо - прочитать начальную справку и выполнить одно элементарное действие... хотя да, кто ж читает правила?